# Is dp to pt conversion ratio 1:1?

Tags: mobile, interaction-design, users, app, interactive-ui

I want to export my design in dp but my all measurement are in points. I tried sending it to the developer but he was not happy. Is pt and dp same for icons and text? Can I send the point dimension for dp?

Comment: This is not a UX question - try asking over on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You probably should send your designs with pixel measurements because pixels are easier to convert to density independent pixels (dp). ([Google Material on dps](https://material.google.com/layout/units-measurements.html#))

Conversion ratio from points to pixels may not be 1:1 as point length is depended on resolution. From Graphic Design Stack Exchange:

> How many pixels = 1pt depends on the resolution of your image. If your image is 72ppi (pixels per inch), then one point will equal exactly one pixel.

[Point vs Pixel: What is the difference?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference)